# Django Generic View Update arguments

Tags: python, django, generics

Hy! I'm a newbie in django, and I want to update my objects when I click on them, but I'm getting the following error:

> NoReverseMatch at /dolgozo/
>   Reverse for 'dolgozo-update' with arguments '(u'pk=dolgozo.id',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'dolgozo/update/(?P\d+)$']

Main urls.py (only the relevant line:):

```
url(r'^dolgozo/', include('DolgozoKarbantart.urls', namespace="dolgozo")),
```

Inner  urls.py

```
url(r'^update/(?P<pk>\d+)$', DolgozoUpdateView.as_view(template_name="DolgozoKarbantart/DolgozoUpdate.html"), name='dolgozo-update'),
```

views.py:

```
class DolgozoUpdateView(UpdateView):
model = Dolgozo
fields = ['dolgozo_id','nev', 'szulido','anyjaneve','telefonszam','lakcim']
template_name = 'DolgozoKarbantart/DolgozoUpdate.html'
```

and I'm trying to pass my argument like this in the html:

```
{% url 'dolgozo:dolgozo-update' 'pk=dolgozo.id' %}
```

Is there anything that is missing from the arguments? Or the view class is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `{% url 'dolgozo:dolgozo-update' pk=dolgozo.id %}` without the quotes around `pk=dolgozo.id`. Please look at [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url) for details.

Comment: Thanks, i corrected it, but it throws error again: `Reverse for 'dolgozo-update' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'dolgozo/update/(?P<pk>\\d+)$']`

Comment: Pretty obvious error, `dolgozo.id` is empty in your template. You need to make sure that it exists.

Comment: Thanks dude, its okay now, i thought i was missing some view arguments or something

Comment: Can i ask you 1 more question? What is this: `TypeError at /dolgozo/update/4
'instance' is an invalid keyword argument for this function` Do i miss something in the view? ( i added to my view: `form_class= Dolgozo` ) Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't tell you the error by just look at one piece of error information. You need to learn how to look at python error stack trace. It's not that hard, find the line in stack trace that's related to your code and try to fix that line. Also, it's not so relevant to current post, so if you still get stuck, try to ask a separate question, other people might benefit from that as well.